Locate table-level meta data describing whether querymore is supported for a particular table in SOQL
I'm accessing table-level data and can choose between the sobjects API or by querying the EntityDefinition table (though more on this later).
Either way, I'm presented with a collection of flags that determine whether the object is queryable, customizable, retrievable etc.
However, when querying the EntityDefinition table over SOQL API, I'm limited to 2000 rows before getting the EntityDefinition does not support queryMore(), use LIMIT to restrict the results to a single batch message.
Where can I find which tables support, or do-not support queryMore()? I'd like to be able to know ahead of time which strategy I need to apply whenever I'm accessing a table, ideally without having to process an error message.
Is there a table or api call, similar to sobjects or EntityDefinition that contains this element of meta-data?
